# How to Make thunderbird consider server date and time for emails?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am a software programmer who works on date related problems very often due to which i have to change system date,

In the mean time if i send or receive any mail then the thunderbird organises my mails by the system date on which the mail was sent or received. This messes up the mail history ie., when the mail is sent or received

Is there any way to make my thunderbird consider serverdate instead of systemdate like how browserbased email clients work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you setup a Virtual Machine were you can do all your testings and use your main machine for actual job, emailing, Word, Excel, Visual Studio or whatever you are using.

Comment: I run 2 eclipse simultaneusly which slows down my system, now running VM will further slow down the system, any ways thanks for the suggestion but I was looking for some setting in thunderbird

Comment: I don't think there such a setting in thunderbird. Why don't you set up another physical machine or upgrade your existing one with more RAM and/or space?